# Opening .resx files in Visual Studio.net gives "The operation cannot be completed. Invalid Pointer" error

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide

I am using Visual Studio 2008. While opening some of the .resx file, it is giving me error that "The operation cannot be completed. Invalid Pointer". What can be the possible problem and solution?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors, change any raster or bitmap font settings to a TrueType font, or simply click OK to have any raster fonts fall back to the default font (Consolas on English systems).  The editor should then load correctly.
Running "devenv /resetuserdata" will also resolve the issue, though it will reset all of your settings to the defaults and therefore change more of your preferences than is necessary to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was invalid xml inside my resx file that was causing the issue.  I posted my answer to this question:

[When opening a .resx file in Visual Studio 2012, gives "The operation could not be completed. Invalid pointer" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304480/when-opening-a-resx-file-in-visual-studio-2012-gives-the-operation-could-not/20104442#20104442)