# When opening a .resx file in Visual Studio 2012, gives "The operation could not be completed. Invalid pointer" error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, resx

I am trying to modify a resx file for a form after setting the form "MainForm" to be localizeable. When I try to open the file "MainForm.resx", it now gives the error "The operation could not be completed. Invalid pointer". I am running Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening .resx files in Visual Studio.net gives "The operation cannot be completed. Invalid Pointer" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950562/opening-resx-files-in-visual-studio-net-gives-the-operation-cannot-be-complete)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because that was a bug that was fixed in VS2008. I am also sometimes getting the error: "The operation could not be completed. Unspecefied error"

Comment: I'm getting this with a project updated from VS2003 and I believe it's caused by empty `<data>` elements. They should contain a `<value/>`. The strange thing is that a different attempt at upgrading the project to VS2012 apparently updated the resx files to include these empty `<value/>` elements automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this exact same issue and it turns out I had some invalid xml in my resx file.

I had the following:

```
<data name="UNIT_MEASURE_CUBE_S1" mimetype="ZONE">
    <value>U/M for Cube</value>
</data>
```

In the above mimetype was the invalid xml.  I removed this so I was left with this:

```
<data name="UNIT_MEASURE_CUBE_S1">
    <value>U/M for Cube</value>
</data>
```

The way I was able to narrow this down was to remove half of the resources within the resx file save it and try to load it in visual studio.  If that worked I knew the problem was in the last 1/2 of the xml.  I continued to do this until I could narrow it down to a small section of the resx file.  Eventually I found my issue.

Comment: In my case, a wayward merge had obliterated the `<value/>` element, which is technically *valid XML* (no xml parse errors, etc.) but obviously not handled well by the RESX designer.

thanks for the tip on "halving"...I was able to do it with an xml comment, which worked pretty well: `<!-- ... -->`

Comment: +1 Very good idea to remove progressively elements in the xml of the reszx file. I've done the same thing and I was able to find the source of the error. Thank you.

Comment: helped me with my problem. the resx files had some data with the attribute "type="System.Resources.ResXNullRef, System.Windows.Forms"" . which was weird, so i changed them with xml:space="preserve"  just like the other data entries. and viola, it works. thanks alot